# How can I have a fixed top bar, with 100% content

Tags: html, css

I have something like this right now... I want the content to be 100% of the page - the 100px from the top bar. But it doesn't work.

```
<style>

#content{
    display: block;
    height: 100%-100px; <!-- I need something to fix this, because it doesnt work -->
}

#topbar{
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone keeps suggesting `margin-top`, however that doesn't play nicely with 100% height.

If you want a true fixed header, try something like this

```
#content {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#topbar {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Update: [Here is a link to a CodePen example](http://cdpn.io/AnJwH)

This is the important code from the example:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topbar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an fiddle where margin-top doesn't play nicely with 100% height? I'm curious...

Comment: Top margin didn't work with mine, it brought down the nav bar http://jsfiddle.net/qbsJH/

Comment: @Arian sorry, use `padding-top`... you don't need the extra box-sizing stuff shown above... that's a bit "hacky" anyhow

Comment: @FastTrack Box sizing is in no way hacky. By default the box model is content-box, which means padding is not included in height and width calculations. In this context you want the padding-top to be included in the height calculation, so we need to change the box model. You might think it's "hacky" because of the browser prefixes, but that just means it does not have full native support across browsers, which is the case for many modern styling.

Comment: @JosephSpens regardless of whether it's hacky or not, the box-sizing isn't needed for his problem so with an interest in brevity, I'd recommend removing it in this specific case.

Comment: @FastTrack I added a CodePen example, hopefully you'll see that box-sizing _is_ needed. I left the prefixes out of the example because it's using [Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/). I would recommend using an autoprefixer like this in your build process.

Try taking out box-sizing, you'll now be able to scroll down the page because the padding is now pushing the content down instead of retracting space from the content.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `padding-top`:

```
#content{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbsJH/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why not give it a bottom margin as:

```
#content {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Use this, it will calculate the total height that you need! :) And apply it then.

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: I think you mean `margin-top` (see my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve the same effect with...

```
#content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your top bar should also use position: fixed; as in @Joseph Spens answer.